# How Spring Data JPA picks up / identifies underlying JPA Provider?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am learning Spring Data JPA, and for that I am writing Simple standalone application. Here is the sample code:

## Entity class --> User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="SSNID")
    private int ssnID;
    @Column(name="FULLNAME")
    private String fullName;
    @Column(name="CITY")
    private String city;
    // Getters and Setters omitted
}
```

## The Repository class --> JPADBAccess.java

```
@Repository
    public interface JPADBAccess extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

    }
```

## A simple service class which uses the repository --> DBServices.java

```
@Service
public class DBServices {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    private JPADBAccess jPADBAccess;  // How does this work?? ---->(1)

    public void saveUser(User user) {

        User queriedUser = null;
        jPADBAccess.save(user);

    }
}
```

## The Spring configuration file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ... ">

<context:annotation-config/> <!-- This enables the annotation's actions, else annotations don't do their work. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.service"/> <!-- This is for component scan -->

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.jpa"/> <!-- This enables support for Spring Data JPA. -->

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
             <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
             <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
          </bean>
      </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/~/test"/>
      <property name="username" value="sa"/>
      <property name="password" value=""/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
       <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
 </bean>
```

## The persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="userPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <class>com.example.model.User</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

The standalone classes looks like this:

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        DBServices dBServices = null;
        User user = new User();
        user.setSsnID(1);
        user.setCity("Blr");
        user.setFullName("Full name");
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
        dBServices = (DBServices) appContext.getBean("DBServices");
        dBServices.saveUser(user);
    }
}
```

Now it works all fine, I am using Hibernate as the JPA provider **(by simply placing the jar's in the classpath)**.

I have following questions:

1) How does DBService gets the instance of JPADBAccess by @Autowire  when there is no bean defined in the configuration file.

```
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private JPADBAccess jPADBAccess;  // How does this work?? ---->(1)
```

2) How does Spring Data JPA uses or infers that the underlying JPA provider is Hibernate, when there is no mention of Hibernate in any of the configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How does DBService gets the instance of JPADBAccess by @Autowire when there is no bean defined in the configuration file.

This is the magic of Spring Data JPA: it finds your repository interface and automatically generates an implementation of it, which is put in the Spring application context. In the class where you autowire `JPADBAccess`, Spring finds the auto-generated implementation.

> 2) How does Spring Data JPA uses or infers that the underlying JPA provider is Hibernate, when there is no mention of Hibernate in any of the configuration file?

But there is, in the `entityManagerFactory` you specified a `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` bean.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. For ques #1, agreed that Spring does provide the implementation on-the-fly, but is there any other way to Inject, other than using @Autowire annotation?

Comment: @CuriousMind there are two ways to inject beans: with an `@Autowired` annotation or by an XML configuration file.

Comment: Yes, that is the confusion I have. Since the bean implementation is provided by Spring on-the-fly, how can I provide the same in the spring config file. If my comment sounds naive, may be due to my lack of understanding, which I want to improve.

Comment: @CuriousMind with `<ref bean="name"/>`, see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-ref-element). You'd need to give your repository bean a name: `@Repository("name")`. But why use XML at all? It is not required to use an XML config file. I prefer not using any XML config at all in Spring projects.

Comment: Thank so much for your info. As I am in the incipient stage of learning, want to really know how the stuff works, otherwise it is remaining as a mystery. I am thankful for your comments. I will dig more, and hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.jpa"/>
```

That line scan all the repositories and create the beans for your, in this case the bean called `JPADBAccess` is being created by you with the power of spring data the implementation is created, so you dont need to write any line of code, and added to the application context.

The selection of the provider comes depending on the classpath, JPA uses some classes to choose the provider as follows

Sometimes the file `META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider` is being searched in the classpath and there will be the name of the provider, in your case you are using the `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` and in the [class code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java) you will see this line that loads hibernate as the provider

```
Class<?> hibernatePersistenceProviderClass = cl.loadClass("org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider");
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply. I got the first part.  For ques#2 I didn't fully understand. In my sample application, I did create the META-INF/ directory and placed the persistency.xml file, but there were no javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider file in there. So, does this mean the service provider is due to the configuration `jpaVendorAdapter`?

Comment: Yes that is correct, if you dont place the file, when the Adapter starts, load the persistence provide automatically without needed to tell, that provider class is within the hibernate jars